# Records Management CSOM API in SharePoint 2016

Tags: csom, records-management, 2016, api

Does anyone know if with SharePoint 2016 (online) we finally get a CSOM interface to the records management functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new version of CSOM released for office 365, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RecordsRepository.Records namespace can help to declare/undeclare item as record. More details about the latest CSOM version can be found [here](https://dev.office.com/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365).